# Select only rows where count of rows in other table is greather than 0

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in my database:

```
Products:
--------------------------------------------------
|   id    |   product_name    |   manufacturer   |
--------------------------------------------------

Products_photos:
-----------------------------------------------
|   id    |   product_id    |   image_name    |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I want select all Products, where Product_photos count is greater than 0.
How I can do that?

@Edit:
I don't want to add results from Products_photos for my output. I want only show entries from Products, where are any images. Sorry for my english :)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the joining solutions already offered are the best bet, in terms of query efficiency.  But for clarity - in terms of expressing exactly what you ask for - I would choose an approach like this:

```
select * from products p
where exists (select * from products_photos pp where pp.product_id = p.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.* FROM Products AS P INNER JOIN Products_Photos AS PP ON P.id=PP.id
```

Another method, more inefficient but maybe better for you to understand, would be

```
SELECT P.* FROM Products AS P
WHERE P.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM Product_photos)
```

Comment: The INNER JOIN will not add the photo information to your output.  Only the Product fields (P.*) will be shown.  The INNER JOIN only includes Products that show up in BOTH tables but the result output is only for Product table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id, p.product_name, p.manufacturer
FROM Products p
     INNER JOIN Products_photos i on i.product_id = p.id
```

Comment: Can you explain me how this: "FROM Products --->p<---" works? Is it this equal to "FROM Products as p"?

Comment: @PiKey, The AS is optional.  Some like it for readability, others consider it clutter.  There is no difference between these two solutions.

Comment: So this is how it works :) Thx. And your example is some wrong for me, because I dont want to add photos for a result. I want display only products, where is any photos.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
Select P.id, P.product_name, P.manufacturer
from Products P 
INNER JOIN Products_photos Pp on P.Id = Pp.product_id
```

For the Inner Join, it will only return rows where it's posible the joining, which means that you have at least one value in the `Products_photos`  table.